# Generic Parameter in typed tuple

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

Consider this minimal example:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Tuple

T = TypeVar("T")
Result = Tuple[bool, T]

def method() -> Result[int]:
    return True, 15
```

Using the official Python plugin for IntelliJ, this results in a type warning on the return value:

```
Expected type 'tuple[int]', got 'tuple[bool, int]' instead
```

While there are certainly other approaches I could implement to achieve my desired result, I am curious about the syntax now. How *would* I describe a type alias for a tuple where one parameter is generic? My searches on google and attempts at using `typing.Generic` have not given me an answer.

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot reproduce with `mypy 0.910`

Comment: Can't reproduce. Which type checker are you using? https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict&gist=72890ee6567824269708e46be0bb89c8

Comment: I am using the official Python plugin for IntelliJ, which, to the best of my ability to tell, uses a custom implementation. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I think that's a bug with the plugin :/ This kind of syntax "should" be supported, and is recognised by other type-checkers such as Mypy.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to make changes in the return type annotation.

Instead of using `Result[int]`, try to keep the return type as `Result` only.

It should look like this.

```
def method() -> Result:
    return True, 15
```

or

```
def method() -> Tuple[bool, T]:
    return True, 15
```

The `Result` is well sufficient to accept `Tuple[bool, T]`.

Comment: The first would not model the same behaviour, as it would allow me to return different types on different branches.

The second is a valid solution, but sidesteps the intent of the question to learn about syntax.

Nonetheless, thanks for answering!

Comment: Edited my answer, basically, it was supposed to be `Result` or `Tuple[bool, T]`.